# Phonegap with Oracle Database Connection

Tags: android, eclipse, oracle, cordova

I have a website based on PHP & Oracle 10g Database

I want to create an android application for this website using Phonegap Framework & Eclipse

I want to know if Phonegap support connection to an EXTERNAL oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you have to create webservice for accessing Oracle 10g database.
2. Then access database via webservice using Javascript/jQuery.

You can get idea by following these tutorials,

http://kmithi.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/8/

http://informationastronaut.blogspot.in/2012/05/get-json-data-from-webservice-using.html

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/